# Copying all files and folders of a directory using tar

Tags: files, tar, file-copy, move, paste

I am trying to copy my files from ssd to external hdd using linux live boot.
The command I'm writing is:

`root@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/4bd92f4b-6b48-4f4a-83ad-9d82d3be488b/home/pegasus# tar cf - Downloads | ( cd /media/ubuntu/Seagate Backup Plus/Downloads; tar xvf -)`

But the problems is all directories aren't getting copied into the hdd.
And no files of downloads are getting copied.
How can I debug it?
How can I use to copy everything from Download directory of my ssd to external hdd using tar?

Files that should be copied:

[image: Files that should be copied:]

Files that are getting copied:

[image]

Comment: what's the reason for this `tar | tar` construct instead of just copying the files using `cp`?

Comment: I've a loads of files, approx 240,000 files to transfer. Using cp is too slow. I'm trying to find a faster way.

Comment: I don't see how this is by any means faster. Why would it? All modern operating systems (I'm guessing this is Linux) have excellent write buffering, and where a `cp` command could quite succesfully make use of the underlying storage queuing abilities, `tar` linearizes the access.

Comment: Idk. I had found it here. 
`https://basila.medium.com/fastest-way-to-copy-a-directory-in-linux-40611d2c5aa4`

Comment: Is this Windows Subsystem For Linux? It doesn't look that way. If it's not, that article you linked to is about a pretty different problem on a different operating system…